# How to get console log when the test fails POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, testing, postman

have a problem with this test.
I want get a `console.log` when the installment value in my JSON is below 100 (when test `FAIL`).
But as result, I have a `PASS` and `FAIL` in test results, that works but I can't get any info in `console.log`. I don't know why my code doesn't work. I thought `else if` would give me the expected result. But still, it doesn't work well.

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody)

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < jsonData[i].products.length; j++) {

    pm.test("Installment > 100", function() {
      if (pm.expect(jsonData[i].products[j].installment).to.be.above(100))
      {
        // Sucess case...
      }
      else if (pm.expect(jsonData[i].products[j].installment).to.be.below(100))
      {
        /// Failure case...
        console.log(jsonData[i].id)
      }
    });
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a situation where you want to use a `try { ... } catch { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pm.expect doesn't return anything , it just throws an Exception (Error) . So you cannot use it in if condition which expects a boolean

**Try any of :**

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody)

for (var i = 0; i <= jsonData.length - 1; i++) {
    {

        for (var j = 0; j <= jsonData[i].products.length - 1; j++)

            pm.test("Installment > 100", function () {
                if (jsonData[i].products[j].installment < 100 && jsonData[i].products[j].installment < 100) console.log(jsonData[i].id)
                pm.expect(jsonData[i].products[j].installment).to.be.above(100)
                pm.expect(jsonData[i].products[j].installment).to.be.below(100)
            });
    }
}
```

Or :

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody)

for (var i = 0; i <= jsonData.length - 1; i++) {
    {

        for (var j = 0; j <= jsonData[i].products.length - 1; j++)

            pm.test("Installment > 100", function () {

                try {
                    pm.expect(jsonData[i].products[j].installment).to.be.above(100)
                } catch (e) {
                    pm.expect(jsonData[i].products[j].installment).to.be.below(100)
                    console.log(jsonData[i].id)
                }

            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, now I have a better understanding of how pm.expect work. Is there no way to get a log when it shows a test error?

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to do , i can console log(e) to see what was the error thrown

Comment: My main goal is get localization in json when an error occurred

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to output to console as well as the test window

```js
pm.test(pm.info.requestName + " - Auth Successful", ...);
console.info(pm.info.requestName + " - Auth Successful");
```